# mongodb - Find document with closest integer value

Tags: mongodb, absolute-value

Let's assume I have a collection with documents with a ratio attribute that is a floating point number.

```
{'ratio':1.437}
```

How do I write a query to find the single document with the closest value to a given integer without loading them all into memory using a driver and finding one with the smallest value of `abs(x-ratio)`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Interesting problem.  I don't know if you can do it in a single query, but you can do it in two:

```js
var x = 1; // given integer
closestBelow = db.test.find({ratio: {$lte: x}}).sort({ratio: -1}).limit(1);
closestAbove = db.test.find({ratio: {$gt: x}}).sort({ratio: 1}).limit(1);
```

Then you just check which of the two docs has the `ratio` closest to the target integer.

**MongoDB 3.2 Update**

The 3.2 release adds support for the [`$abs`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/abs/#abs-aggregation) absolute value aggregation operator which now allows this to be done in a single `aggregate` query:

```js
var x = 1;
db.test.aggregate([
    // Project a diff field that's the absolute difference along with the original doc.
    {$project: {diff: {$abs: {$subtract: [x, '$ratio']}}, doc: '$$ROOT'}},
    // Order the docs by diff
    {$sort: {diff: 1}},
    // Take the first one
    {$limit: 1}
])
```

Comment: This aggregation method also works good with datetimes, then the difference is the milliseconds between the desired point in time and the nearest one existing in the dataset.

Comment: Is is this kind of aggregation smart enough to use an index for `ratio` effectively? I suspect the first solution with two requests to the DB might be faster for larger collections.

Comment: I'm doing something similar, but with 5 parameters. I want to find the optimal matching document to the query values: { 'a' : 1.1, 'b' : 0.3, 'c' : 0.01, 'd' : 1.8, 'e' : 0.55}. How would I do this cleanly?

Answer (score 9):

I have another idea, but very tricky and need to change your data structure.

You can use [geolocation index](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) which supported by mongodb

First, change your data to this structure and keep the second value with 0

```
{'ratio':[1.437, 0]}
```

Then you can use `$near` operator to find the the closest ratio value, and because the operator return a list sorted by distance with the integer you give, you have to use `limit` to get only the closest value.

```
db.places.find( { ratio : { $near : [50,0] } } ).limit(1)
```

If you don't want to do this, I think you can just use @JohnnyHK's answer :)

Comment: I had considered applying geolocation this way... I think I'm going to give this a shot.  The ratio value is actually an aspect ratio of an image, so I could treat widthxheight as a dimensional query.

Comment: I'm considering something similar. Did you have any luck with this approach?

Comment: Wow... I could not have thought of that.