# MongoDB: How to get the document that contains the numeric value closest to a given number

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the following MongoDB documents...

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e67b28010000880ca4c043"), "amount" : { "value" : 1.125, "currency" : "USD" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e897e60100009f0051da48"), "amount" : { "value" : 1.525, "currency" : "USD" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55ea1b520100006d004e602a"), "amount" : { "value" : 1.825, "currency" : "USD" } }
```

How do I get the document with `amount.value` closest to 2.0 (1.825 in this case)? For instance, I need to create a query that takes a number as the input and returns the document with `amount.value` closest to the specified number.

Comment: and if you have the value 2.1 what you want to return ?

Comment: Still 1.825... I need to find the closest number, regardless of whether the given number is less or greater.

Comment: Will you flexible to change the value to "value" : [1.125,0]  ?

Comment: That's a bit difficult since such a change would affect a lot of code... what's the second number for?

Comment: MongoDB supports geolocation index, which will support $near, but if you are not comfortable you can go with ans given by Nishant  below

Comment: Let me give a look...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongodb - Find document with closest integer value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275491/mongodb-find-document-with-closest-integer-value) and worth noting that every response here is based on the content in the answers provided there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish it in two queries.

```js
providedValue = 1.34;

closestBelow = db.test.find({
    "amount.value": {
    $lte: providedValue
    }
}).sort({
    amount.value: -1
}).limit(1);

closestAbove = db.test.find({
    "amount.value": {
    $gte: providedValue
    }
}).sort({
    amount.value: 1
}).limit(1);
```

You can check this link, for further details
[mongodb - Find document with closest integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275491/mongodb-find-document-with-closest-integer-value)

Comment: I am thinking about wether this can be achieved through a linked list created with an aggregation or sth. Would save a query during runtime...