# Get documents sorted by distance from an integer?

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting

Mongo has a [`$near`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) query operator, which "[s]pecifies a point for which a geospatial query returns the documents from nearest to farthest."

Is there an equivalent for integers? That is, say I have a collection of documents with `amount` fields, which are integers. I want to get the documents in order of the amounts closes to a given amount.

For example, say I have this collection (mongo shell):

```
> db.foob.find({}, {amount: 1, _id: 0})
{ "amount" : 10 }
{ "amount" : 20 }
{ "amount" : 50 }
{ "amount" : 100 }
{ "amount" : 1000 }
{ "amount" : 1100 }
{ "amount" : 1300 }
```

I want something like this:

```
> db.foob.find({}, {amount: 1, _id: 0}).sortByClosestTo({amount: 400})
{ "amount" : 100 }
{ "amount" : 50 }
{ "amount" : 20 }
{ "amount" : 10 }
{ "amount" : 1000 }
{ "amount" : 1100 }
{ "amount" : 1300 }
```

If there is no built-in query operator for this, is there any way to accomplish this sort short of getting the entire collection and doing a `.sort(key=lambda doc: abs(doc['amount'] - n)`?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275491/mongodb-find-document-with-closest-integer-value

Comment: @Bahrom: That does give me some ideas!

Comment: @Bahrom: Yes, in fact, this is a duplicate of that - good find!